# Prove this sequence is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove this sequence is decreasing for all $0<x<1$ and $ x>1$:
>   $$n(x^{1/n} -1)$$

I've tried showing $(n+1)(x^{\frac{1}{n+1}} -1)<n(x^{1/n} -1)$ by separating into the cases $x>1$ and $x<1$ but end up with the inequality $nx^{\frac{1}{n+1}} + x^{\frac{1}{n+1}} < nx^{1/n} + 1$ and can only prove that $ x^{1/n} <  x^{\frac{1}{n+1}}< 1$ or vice versa depending on the case, which does not definitively prove the first inequality.

Answer (score 1):

The AM-GM inequality yields:

$$\frac{nx^{1/n} + 1}{n+1} \ge \left( (x^{1/n})^n \times 1 \right)^{1/{n+1}} = x^{1/(n+1)}$$

with equality only when $x = 1$. This proves your result.

Comment: Unfortunately, the course hasn't covered the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: It's a calculus class, yes? AM-GM is strictly pre-calculus and is generally assumed. It's an easy proof by induction you should give it a go.